# How to remote debug a driver on recent laptop with Windbg

Tags: debugging, driver, windbg, remote-debugging

I have a recent ultrabook laptop with just one USB-C port, no PCIe NIC Ethernet, no serial port, no firewire. I need to debug a Wifi driver on this laptop that displays BSOD punctually.
I have no other choice but to use remote debugging, and it seems that my only option is to use USB3 debugging cable. So far I have tried to build a crossover USB3 debug cable without any success. So I ordered one.
While waiting for delivery, are there other possibilities to debug this kind of driver? Any idea?

Note: full memdump doesn't enough, I need to place breakpoints, watch values, trace...

Comment: quite often laptops are equipped with replaceable mini pci-e cards to provide wifi/bluetooth. And there are adapters which allow us to stick such mini pci-e cards into regular pc pci-e slots. I wonder about possibility to debug your driver at regular PC which has serial port... Does it make any sense to you?